# fetch data from MSSQL server by ajax through Php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server, ajax

I am using AJAX to retrieve data from MSSQL server 2017 using Php and show those values in a text box. One MSSQL query is giving but other doesn't.
In **data.php** when `$stmt` here is equals to `SELECT rmtype FROM rmmaster`, data is loading to text box in **AJAX.php** but when `$stmt` here is equals to `SELECT * FROM rmmaster where rmnumber='102'` this doesn't have values. But if run both the queries in sql managment studio, both are working and have results.

No error in connections, Just this working to one and not to other.

> This is AJAX.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <button type="button" id="element" class="element">Button</button>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">

</div>

</body>

<script type="application/javascript">
    $('#element').on('click', function(e){
       $.ajax({
            url: 'data.php',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data){
               alert(data);
                $('#usr').val(data);

            }
        });
    });
</script>




</html>
```

> This is DATA.php

```
 include_once ('home.php');
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


$name="102";

$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM rmmaster where rmnumber='$name'"); // this is not giving results
//$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT rmtype FROM rmmaster"); // this is giving answers

if( $stmt === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

if( $stmt->fetch() === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo ($row['rmtype'].$name);

}
```

home.php is the data connection to the sql server and no error in that file.

Comment: But here one query is fetching results other does not.

Comment: is there a row in the table where rmnumber = 102? is rmnumber an integer or a varchar/text?

Comment: yes there is a record for 102, its in the char format. I tried passing 102 in both integer and char formats.

Comment: have you tried hard coding 102 into the query (for debug) eg. "SELECT * FROM rmmaster where rmnumber='102'" .what happens when you try this?

Comment: yes i did, But it doesn't load values to the text box. But when typed in management studio it gives out records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is always reading the first result row and then doing nothing with it, basically ignoring it.

This If reads the first row from the result set

```
if( $stmt->fetch() === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

So remove that IF and it will work when you are only selecting one row and also will return all the rows when you are selecting more than one row

```
include_once ('home.php');
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


$name="102";

$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM rmmaster where rmnumber='$name'"); // this is not giving results
//$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT rmtype FROM rmmaster"); // this is giving answers

if( $stmt === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

/*
if( $stmt->fetch() === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
*/

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo ($row['rmtype'].$name);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you!, Yes this did the work.
But is there any other way to find whether the query is a null OR have values?

Comment: The IF before the removed one should do that